# FrostWire Not Installing

Tags: apt

When I try to install FrostWire on 14.04 LTS, it says

```
Dependency is not satisfiable: openjdk-8-jre
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

[image: Here is a picture of the error]

Comment: Use instead `sudo apt-get install frostwire`, `apt-cache policy frostwire openjdk-8-jre` and `apt-cache depends frostwire`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to manually install `openjdk-8-jdk` first.

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

---

When the `openjdk-8-jdk` installation is done, try to reinstall `frostwire` :

```
wget http://dl1.frostwire.com/frostwire/6.1.9/frostwire-6.1.9.all.deb
sudo dpkg -i frostwire-6.1.9.all.deb
```

Answer (score 2):

[@hg8](https://askubuntu.com/users/338915/hg8)s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/715050/367165) is perfect, but I have an alternative solution, remove the `openjdk-8-jre` dependency and install a Java 8 of your choice:

1. Extract the DEB package

   ```
   dpkg -x frostwire-6.1.9.all.deb frostwire
   ```
2. Go into the extracted folder and extract the control file

   ```
   cd frostwire
   dpkg -e ../frostwire-6.1.9.all.deb
   ```
3. Remove the dependency

   ```
   sed 's/openjdk-8-jre,//' DEBIAN/control
   ```
4. Re-build the DEB package

   ```
   cd ..
   dpkg -b frostwire
   ```
5. Install the new DEB package

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i frostwire.deb
   ```
6. Install your preferred Java 8, e.g. Oracle Java 8

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
   sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle
   ```

   or an other Java 8 of your choice.

Comment: I think it might be worth mentioning that one would have to repeat this on every update of frostwire. I do think that the frostwire dependency should be on java-8, (or such, can't recall what the generic java-8 dependency thing is), so that may be a bug for upstream to fix.